# List return Last item only mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

below is my Action Method.It return Last item of list only. but I want list of Items in AList.

```
public ActionResult Ataxi(){
        List<sub_employee> AList = new List<sub_employee>();
        var alist = IM.getAvailableList().ToList();
        foreach(var item in alist)
        {
             AList = db.sub_employee.Where(s => s.SE_ID == item).ToList();
        }
        return View(AList);

    }
```

how do I get All elements in Alist. Can Somebody help me to solve this problem. thank you

Comment: You keep overwriting the value of `AList ` in each iteration of the `foreach` loop. Best guess is you want `Alist.AddRange(....)`

Comment: I want all elements which are intersect alist and sub_employee model class

Comment: No one can help without knowing your models or what your queries return. I assume you want `AList.AddRange(db.sub_employee.Where(s => s.SE_ID == item))`

Comment: `public ActionResult Ataxi()
        {
            List<sub_employee> AList = new List<sub_employee>();
            var alist = IM.getAvailableList().ToList();
            foreach(var item in alist)
            {
                AList.AddRange(db.sub_employee.Where(s => s.SE_ID == item));
            }
            return View(AList);
            
        }`  also correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
public ActionResult Ataxi(){
    var list1 = IM.getAvailableList().ToList();
    var list2 = db.sub_employee
        .Where(x => list1.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToList();
    return View(list2);
}
```

In your example you keep overwriting the value of the list.  You also check `Where` for each item of your original list against `db.sub_employee`, which is hard to read and not very efficient.  You really only need to use `Where` once to filter the value whose key is not already in the list. Note that using `Contains` inside `Where` is horribly inefficient, but its simple to write and doesn't require creating new LINQ operators.

Also, on a style note, I would avoid starting local variable names with capital letters (`Alist`), and especially avoid local variables that only differ by capitalization (`Alist` vs `alist`).  Conversely, it is standard to name types and properties starting with capital letters (`sub_employee`).

Comment: what is Id ? it doesn't exist

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation on my problem.It was great to newbies to learn basics.

Comment: I meant `SE_ID` when I wrote `Id`.  You don't need to call `AddRange` in a loop though, you can use LINQ for the whole thing.  `var AList = IM.getAvailableList().Select(item => db.sub_employee.Where(s => s.SE_ID == item));`